# Ruby's ReadLine word wrap

Tags: ruby, readline, irb, pry

I'm using Ruby's `ReadLine` library to implement a CLI.

I'm getting a weird behaviour with typing lines that are longer then the terminal width. Instead of continuing the text in a new line (like Bash does), the line gets overlapped. So the instead of going down one line, the input overrides the current line from the beginning of it.

`Readline` exposes `screen_size`, so I can create a new thread that listens to `Readline`'s `line_buffer` and puts a new line whenever the length of the line equals the width of the terminal, but it feels wrong.

Is there another option? I saw that `IRB` and `pry` both use `Readline` and do support word wrap, however I couldn't figure how they do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution is quite simple:

```
apt-get install ncurses-dev
```

Apparently, this seems to work, for whatever reason.